# Как добавить динамический параметр итерации в цикл for?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно прописать `$i++` в зависимости от параметра `$step` ?

Например если `$step = 1` то в цикле `for $i++`, или например в `$step = 10` то `$i+=10`

Параметр `$step` это шаг насколько увеличивать цикл

```
function get_html_options(int $min, int $max, int $selected, int $step = 1) {
    $options = '';
    for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        if ($i == $selected) {
            $options .= "<option value='{$i}' selected>{$i}</option>";
        } else {
            $options .= "<option value='{$i}'>{$i}</option>";
        }
    }
    return $options;
}

get_html_options(100, 1000, $config['tickers-timer'], 10)
```

Comment: `$i += $step` ?

Comment: еще вам упрощу `$sel = $i == $selected ? " selected" : "";` и `<option $sel>`

Comment: @teran, а `$i++` и `$i+=1` это получается одно и тоже?

Comment: да, одно и то же

Comment: @teran спасибо за короткий пример выше, когда меньше кода удобно ориентироваться